# Divide HH:mm:ss string data with integer value

Tags: php

I have some string value with time format ie `20:30:00` and I want to divide it by `2` (this is an integer value referencing to number of hours), and expected result must be `10:30:00`.
What I have heard is that I need to change it string time format to seconds and then divide it but I don't have any sample to compute it.

Comment: Surely `20:30:00` divided by two is `10:15:00`, no?

Comment: What is half of `01:00:00`, `00:30:00`?

Comment: 00:300:00 is the right answer chris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fairly simple using the date function with a time argument.  strtotime will convert the time to an integer (unix timestamp).

```
date('H:i:s', strtotime($time)/2);
```