# divide PHP time (h:i)

Tags: php, time, divide

I have an employee timesheet where durations are divided by the number of days an employee works.

E.g 25:00 over 3 days = `25:00/3=08:20`

I have tried the simple divide query above, however this does not show a result. Is it possible to divide a h:m string?

Comment: not a string.. try typecasting to float

Comment: split on `:`, convert to integer, convert hours to minutes, add remaining minutes, divide by three, reconvert to `hour:minutes`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Divide HH:mm:ss string data with integer value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32239524/divide-hhmmss-string-data-with-integer-value)

Comment: convert in to minute and device by 3 then again convert in to hour: minute format. it's simple.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563535/convert-number-of-minutes-into-hours-minutes-using-php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best approach would be to convert to seconds and use date to display it.

```
$time ="25:00";
$days = 3;

list($hours, $minutes) = explode(":", $time);
$minutes += $hours*60;
$seconds = $minutes*60;
date_default_timezone_set ("UTC");
echo "new time: " . date("h:i", $seconds/$days);
```

See the result [here](https://3v4l.org/bgOni)